# App on iOS Simulator has no connection

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm running my app with `react-native run-ios` but when it's built it won't load any data because the network connection failed.

However, browsing the Internet through the simulator does work. So there is a connection, it's just not working with my apps.

I'm building on iPhone 6 simulator.

I have tried

- `Simulator > reset`
- `Settings > Developer > Allow HTTP Services`

but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are using HTTP connections. App Transport Security (iOS 9.0 and above) forces app to use HTTPS. The best you can do is start using HTTPS. Or disable it at least for now, because in January 1, 2017 Apple will reject your app, if you won't give them good explanation of why you are using non secure connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have changed everything to HTTPS but it's still not making any connection

Comment: Weird... don't you get any warnings/errors in console?

Comment: No, only the 'network failed' error from my `catch` functions